# Arabic support db,php & js

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, mysqli

When I type a comment in Arabic inside a textarea, it directly appears in site correctly "عربي" and send it to database.

When I refresh the page it appears like this "Ø¹Ø±Ø¨Ù�"

I tried to type some text directly in database using "phpMyAdmin" and my site shows it
like this "?????".

I used this code in my HTML pages:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="windows-1256">
```

And the encoding of the Database is utf8_unicode_ci.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Everything should be set to utf-8 throught. Remove this `<meta charset="windows-1256">`

Answer (score 0):

try executing this query before all others :

```
$query="SET NAMES utf8";
```